# Multiple server blocks - Could not resolve host

Tags: nginx, lua

I am trying to create two different server blocks in nginx. I have:

...

```
env first_var;
env second_var;

http {
    ...    
    server { 
      set_by_lua $first_var 'return os.getenv("FIRST_VAR")';
      server_name $first_var;
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80;
      ...
    }   

    server {
      set_by_lua $second_var 'return os.getenv("SECOND_VAR")';
      server_name $second_var;
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      ...
    }   
}
```

When I try to reach the second server I get: Could not resolve host: myhost.com. I get the same message if I change the order of the server blocks. However, if I comment out the first server block the second one works (but then I'm not able to get to the first server). Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems that default_server is screwing everything up....I'd like to keep that but how?

Comment: It's probable that `server_name` does not resolve the variable and you are setting the server name to the name of the variable rather than its value.